# Find position of left top corner when finish dragging div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div container and inside couple divs with class demo like

```
<div id='container' style='width:500px;height:500px;'>
<div class='demo' style='width:100px;height:100px;'></div>
<div class='demo' style='width:100px;height:100px;'></div>
<div class='demo' style='width:100px;height:100px;'></div>

</div>
```

and function inside ready in jquery

```
$(function(){
$('.demo').draggable()
.resizable({
stop:function(event,ui){}
alert(ui.size.width+' '+ui.size.height);
})

});
```

How to fetch position of left top corner (relative to parent div id=container) when I finish dragging div with class='demo' insider parent div id="container"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`stop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop) and [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) methods

```
$(function(){
    $('.demo').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            alert('Left:' + $(this).position().left + ' Top:' + $(this).position().left);
        }
    }).resizable({
        stop:function(event,ui){}
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .position();

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the offset parent.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var top = $('#container').css('top')

and 

var left = $('#container').css('left')
```

Comment: btw the reason of giving this suggestion was because I noted that you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
$('.demo').draggable()
.resizable({
stop:function(event,ui){}
alert($(this).css("top")+' '+$(this).css("left"));
})

});
```

May be it is correct